# Recursive Top to Bottom Parent and it's Child

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @table as table
 (
  Id int,
  ParentId int
 )


 insert into @table
 values (1 , null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2),(6,3),(7,3)


  ;with cte 
    as (select Id,ParentId,1 as [level]
        from @table as t 
        where ParentId is null
        UNION ALL
        select t.Id,t.ParentId , cte.level + 1
        from @table as t 
        join cte 
        on t.ParentId = cte.Id)
    select *
    from cte
```

| Id | ParentId | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |

I want to get Top to Bottom Parent -> it's all descendants

and again Top to Bottom Parent -> it's descendants
but I am unable to get expected output using above query

expected output vertically in table

Id 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5

Id 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7

**expected output**

| Id | ParentId | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 |

A tree Starts from 1 and goes to bottom to find it's all child

1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5

again tree Starts from 1 and goes to bottom to find it's all child

1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the data set you expect to be returned?

Comment: This looks like a homework / interview question. I will give you hint: in the final select you need to joint cte with itself.

Comment: oh yes! @PatrickHurst I have updated my question with an expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @table as table
 (
  Id int,
  ParentId int
 )


 declare @cte as table
 (
  Id int,
  ParentId int 
 )

 declare @output as table
 (
  Id int,
  ParentId int
 
 )
  
 insert into @table
 values (1,null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2),(6,3),(7,3)

 declare @id int 
 declare @parentid int
  

  ;with cte 
    as (select Id,ParentId
        from @table as t 
        where ParentId is null
        UNION ALL
        select t.Id,t.ParentId 
        from @table as t 
        join cte 
        on t.ParentId = cte.Id)
     insert into @cte
    select *
    from cte  
     
     
     declare @start int = 1
     declare @end int = (select count(ParentId) from @cte where ParentId= (select Id from @cte where ParentId is null))

     while(@start <= @end)
     begin
     
     select top 1 @id = Id  ,@parentid=ParentId from @cte where ParentId = (select Id from @cte where ParentId is null) 

     if(@id > 0 )
     begin

     insert into @output
     select * from @cte where ParentId is null

     insert into @output values (@id,@parentid)
     delete from @cte where Id = @id and ParentId = @parentid  

     insert into @output
     select * from @cte where ParentId = @id

     delete from @cte where Id  in (select Id from @cte where ParentId = @id)

     end
      
     set @start+=1
     end


     select * from @output
```

**thank you guys for your help i figured it out by myself.**
**it would be nice if any of you guys improve my answer, it is not best solution but currently it is what it is**